# How to send Data from the Ras Pi Pico to Ras Pi 4.0?

Tags: python, pi-4, pi-pico

I have a Ras Pi Pico which I am using for data collection due to the required sampling frequency. I would like to collect that data and send to the Ras Pi 4.0 so I can use the data elsewhere. Is this possible if so can you guide me how to do this please?

Comment: Of course it is possible.  However this is not a tutorial site, you need to do your own research and ask a question if you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Joan, I am very new at this. All I wanted was a starting point as I didnt even know what to research to begin. And to me asking something like this on here is research, its maybe not the classical method but any means of information gathering is research isnt it. So why could I not ask for guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you few ideas, not exact tutorial here.

There are many protocols you can use to achieve this.

1. UART of Rpi Pico <--> UART of Rpi4 ( dont forget cross connect RX & TX of each other pi's.)
2. Use SPI
3. I2C
4. Use a http server on pi4 using python code , and add http client on pico
   ... There are endless possibilities like these.
   If you want very simple and fast implementation, I personally recommend to use UART for small size of data transfer, else use ethernet based http server/client if data is huge.